What is the distinction between theft and fraud?
There have been a number of "thefts" reported in UK news over the last few days.  From reading the details these mostly sound more like fraud to me, in that the goods were delivered to the criminals with the expectation that they would take ownership of them, but they were not paid for.  Would these crimes be prosecuted as thefts, or are they examples of fraud, and the media and perhaps the police are being inexact?
Cheesemakers in shock as £300,000 of produce stolen in sophisticated scam

The company delivered 22 tonnes of cheddar after being approached by a person posing as wholesale distributor for a big French retailer.
The Metropolitan police said: “On Monday, 21 October, we received a report of the theft of a large quantity of cheese from a manufacturer based in Southwark. Enquiries are ongoing into the circumstances.”

Edited to add today's news:

Detectives investigating the theft of 22 tonnes of cheese from Neal’s Yard Dairy have arrested a 63-year-old man on suspicion of fraud by false representation and handling stolen goods.

This raises a question, are fraudulently obtained goods "stolen", or does that require theft?
Authorities need to act over ‘high-end food fraud’, says scammed salmon firm

The company owned by Swales was convinced to part with a substantial quantity of smoked salmon after an order was made by a man posing as a representative of a French supermarket.
The buyer – who gave his name as Patrick Moulin - ordered four metric tonnes of salmon, cut into 1kg portions, to be delivered in two batches 21 days apart.
“Moulin” went back on his word and insisted he would pay for both orders together, before later disappearing from contact when questioned further.

Fleet of 30 luxury cars taken to Thailand returned to UK, police say

A fleet of 30 luxury cars worth £6.5m whisked out of the UK to Thailand after being fraudulently bought on finance have been recovered and returned, police have said.

NaVCIS assist Hertfordshire Police in £2 million car finance fraud investigation

Several men were given fake identity documents by an organised crime group that had made fraudulent credit agreements using stolen information. Once credit had been finalised with car dealers across the country, it was arranged for the men, who were known as ‘strikers’, to collect cars from different locations such as hotel car parks.
The fraud ran from February 2020 to July 2022 during which time 75 cars, including Porsches, Mercedes and BMWs valued at more than £2 million, were stolen.

A somewhat different case is the one that was taken after be rented not bought.  I guess this would be theft because there was never an intent to transfer ownership?

The Lamborghini Huracán Spyder is being reunited with its owner, who runs a company renting out supercars.


Note that news headlines and articles are not obligated to use legal terminology correctly, and they frequently do not. A reporter can call something a robbery that was actually a theft, and they won't get in trouble.

There is certainly overlap. There can be a theft which is not a fraud (you take somebody's stuff but without deception), and a fraud which is not a theft (you deceive somebody to their detriment but you don't get any of their property). But there is plenty of conduct which could be seen as both, in which case it's up to the prosecutor how to proceed.
Guidance from the Crown Prosecution Service has this to say, applicable to england-and-wales (links added by me):

Given the wide interpretation which the courts have made of the elements of theft there is obviously a great deal of overlap between theft and the various offences under the Fraud Act. Where the offence consists of taking something without permission then for ease of presentation prosecutors should charge it under TA 1968. Where it consists of tricking somebody into parting with possession then it will usually be better to charge it under the Fraud Act.
(Legal Guidance - Theft Act Offences)

and

In many cases fraud will also be theft. Prosecutors should bear in mind:

Theft carries a lower maximum sentence;
The actus reus requirement for fraud is far less;
The credit/debit status of any bank accounts debited is irrelevant to the Fraud Act offences. All that is in issue is the Defendant's right to use the account;
It is not necessary to prove or demonstrate any consequences of fraud (though they will clearly be material to sentence, compensation and confiscation). "Preddy" type difficulties will not arise (where the property obtained had not belonged to another);
Fraud Act offences do not require an intent permanently to deprive;
A charge should describe what actually happened and reflect the true criminality; and
The indictment should be as simple as reasonably possible.

In some cases there will be other possible offences such as False Accounting (section 17 Theft Act 1968), Making off Without Payment (section 3 Theft Act 1978), Obtaining Services Dishonestly (Section 11 Fraud Act 2006), offences under the Computer Misuse Act 1990, Forgery and Counterfeiting Act 1981, the Identity Cards Act 2006, the Proceeds of Crime Act 2002 or the Financial Services and Markets Act 2000.
Prosecutors must decide which offence properly reflects the criminality concerned.
(Legal Guidance - Fraud Act 2006)

In scotland these offences are known at common-law rather than possessing a statutory definition, but essentially the same thing is going on.

'It is not necessary to prove or demonstrate any consequences of fraud' - yes. people in the UK have been prosecuted for CV/resumé fraud (by falsely claiming to have, or inflating the grade of, educational qualifications) when they merely applied for a job which they did not actually get.
